# Executing an SSRS 2012 report cause the browser not to respond

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm

I am using Dynamics CRM 2013 on premise.

I have built all the reports based on stored procedures in SSRS. 
one report however, that has no issue with execution definitions, permissions or what ever,
once executed causes to browser to crash (any browser, i tried FF, Chrome, IE9 and up, )
it seems the problem is not a report execution problem but a report rendering problem for this specific report.

I cannot cache the report or make a snapshot of it, as the values of the reports also depends on the user running the report (among other parameters user-defined) and each user should get a different result. - i have more than 400 users.

I have tried searching for any one who had face this kind of issue and reported on it but failed. hence decided to post this question my self.

if anyone has any idea, please share.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled tracing/logging in SSRS? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156500.aspx

You might turn on verbose logging while trying to run the report to see if you can get more helpful information.

If you write code, you can write a .NET application that calls the SSRS web services to render the report. Doing that will help you know for certain whether it's a browser rendering issue since you can get back the report as a byte array and save it to disk as Word, PDF, etc.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have enabled the logs and checked them and got nothing,

Comment: it writes that it processes the report but nothing after that.